# Hardness of the Minimum Steiner Tree problem on grid

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Is the **Minimum Steiner Tree** problem $NP$-hard even on (2D, unweighted) grid graph ? A proof (for either case) will be very appreciated.

Comment: Garey, Graham, and Johnson 1977 showed NP-completeness for the version of the problem where vertices of the original graph and the required Steiner tree all have integer coordinates.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not translate straightforward to hardness on grid graphs.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon: I appreciate their abstract, "This effectively destroys any hope for finding an efficient algorithm for this problem."

Answer (score 1):

This problem is $NP$-complete as shown by a reduction from **Rectilinear Steiner Minimum Tree** (RSMT) problem. Consider the Hanan grid: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanan_grid. Since Planar-3-SAT is strongly NP-complete, we can subdivide every segment of this grid into unit segments to obtain a grid graph.